# Implementation of a general-purpose object structure (property bag)

Tags: c#, .net, oop, dynamic

We need to implement some general-purpose object structure, much like an object in dynamic languages, that would give us a possibility of creating the whole object graph on-the-fly. This class has to be serializable and somehow user friendly.

So far we have made some experiments with class derived from `Dictionary<string, object>` using the dot notation path to store properties and collections in the object tree. We have also find an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/propertybag.aspx) that implements something similar, but it doesn't seem to fit completely into our picture either.

Do you know about some good implementations / libraries that deal with a similar problem or do you have any (non-trivial) ideas that could help us with our own implementation ?

Also, I probably have to say that we are using .NET 3.5, so we can't take advantage of the new features in .NET 4.0 like dynamic type etc. (as far as I know it's also not possible to use any subset of it in .NET 3.5 solution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done property-bag implementations in the past, including all the muck like `ICustomTypeDescriptor` / `ITypedList` to get it binding - and it can be a **lot** of work. Especially if you include serialization (not including `BinaryFormatter`, which has its own issues).

This type of dynamic object doesn't *really* fit very well in a *generally* statically typed language like C#, but it can be made to work. While I'm not their greatest fan (not even a little), could you perhaps just use `DataTable` / `DataRow` here? It does what you ask, without the many man-hours development / debugging.

Answer (score 3):

One class that's easy to dynamically add properties to (in a hierarchical manner) and serialize is `XDocument`.

You're not going to get much easier to use unless you move to .Net 4.

I particularly like the way they've added explicit cast operators:

```
XElement address = d.Element("Address");
int number = (int)address.Attribute("Number");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this CodeProject article that explains how to set up a property bag to be used with a property grid [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/bending_property.aspx), and also [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/propertybag.aspx). I used these as there was an emphasis on your question in relation to a property bag.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: The second one is the same that I have posted. But I will check out the first one, thanks ;)